# AWS lambda almacenar en S3, access denied

Tags: nodejs, aws, lambda, amazon-s3

estoy creando una función en Lambda y quiero almacenar algo en S3.
De momento es solo un texto (luego almacenare una response de un servidor).
La función me devuelve un "access denied"
La he creado desde mi cuenta y soy el Admin.
Me falta darle algún permiso a la función Lambda?
El s3 esta seteado para ser de acceso público

```
const AWS = require('aws-sdk');
const S3 = new AWS.S3();
exports.handler = (event, context, callback) => {
const upload = async () => {
    const params = {
        ACL: "public-read",
        Body: "Hello from Lambda",
        ContentType: "text/html",
        Bucket: "lambda-gps-storage",
        Key: "gpstextfile.txt"
    };
    return await new Promise ((resolve, reject) => {
        S3.putObject(params, (err, results) => {
            if(err) reject(err);
            else resolve(results);
        });
    });
};
callback(null, upload());
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AWS dispone de un sistema de permisos cuya configuración por defecto es denegar cualquier operación.

Es decir, para que un servicio pueda interactuar con otro servicio o recurso es necesario darle los permisos pertinentes.

En concreto, lo que tienes que hacer es editar el rol de la lambda y permitir las solicitudes al sevicio S3 de tipo `put-object`. Lo suyo sería limitar esta operación solo al bucket que te interesa (e incluso si consigues que la petición sea más restrictiva, mejor).

Un posible ejemplo del permiso sería el siguiente:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        # Otros permisos ...
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": ["s3:PutObject"],
            "Resource": "arn_de_tu_bucket/gpstextfile.txt"
        }
    ]
}
```